# Rails saving and/or caching complicated query results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have an application that, at its core, is a sort of data warehouse and report generator. People use it to "mine" through a large amount of data with ad-hoc queries, produce a report page with a bunch of distribution graphs, and click through those graphs to look at specific result sets of the underlying items being "mined." The problem is that the database is now many hundreds of millions of rows of data, and even with indexing, some queries can take longer than a browser is willing to wait for a response.

Ideally, at some arbitrary cutoff, I want to "offline" the user's query, and perform it in the background, save the result set to a new table, and use a job to email a link to the user which could use this as a cached result to skip directly to the browser rendering the graphs. These jobs/results could be saved for a long time in case people wanted to revisit the particular problem they were working on, or emailed to coworkers. I would be tempted to just create a PDF of the result, but it's the interactive clicking of the graphs that I'm trying to preserve here.

None of the standard Rails caching techniques really captures this idea, so maybe I just have to do this all by hand, but I wanted to check to see if I wasn't missing something that I could start with. I could create a keyed model result in the in-memory cache, but I want these results to be preserved on the order of months, and I deploy at least once a week.

Comment: I'm thinking this is more a issue that should be solved on the database layer with something like a materialized view or a table(s) which contains the data generated from a report. Caching isn't really suitible if you need to store the results for extended peroids of time.

Comment: I second @max's solution. Use PostgreSQL for Materialized View and also have a look at scenic Gem.

Comment: I can't predict what the users will be searching for, as that changes per customer requests. So I can't make views in the database ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

Considering Data loading from lots of join tables. That's why it's taking time to load.
Also you are performing calculation/visualization tasks with the data you fetch from DB, then show on UI.

I like to recommend some of the approaches to your problem:

- Minimize the number of joins/nested join DB queries
- Add some direct tables/columns, ex. If you are showing counts of comments of user the you can add new column in user table to store it in user table itself. You can add scheduled job to update data or add callback to update count
- also try to minimize the calculations(if any) performing on UI side
- you can also use the concept of lazy loading for fetching the data in chunks

Thanks, hope this will help you to decide where to start